# Powershell: regex replace с вычислением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, powershell

Есть файлы, именованные годом/месяцем `yyyymm`, и мне необходимо переименовать их наоборот `mmyyyy`, но при этом месяц `mm` в имени должен стать на один меньше. И вся трудность заключается в том, что мне нужно сделать это одной строчкой.

Я могу переименовать с помощью regex replace `abc2017`**`06`**`.txt` в `abc`**`06`**`2017.txt` с помощью паттерна

> `'abc201706.txt' -replace '^(.*)([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})(\..*)$','$1$3$2$4'`

Но как мне переименовать его в `abc`**`05`**`2017.txt`?
Другими словами, мне необходимо в этой строке вычесть один месяц из `$3`, который соответствует первоначальному месяцу.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 1):

Просто одной строчкой нельзя. Если есть необходимость сделать всё с помощью одного метода `Regex.Replace()`, вам необходимо использовать функцию обратного вызова в качестве аргумента замены. Передав в этот метод аргумент совпадения необходимо конвертировать строку даты в объект *DateTime* для правильного расчета новой даты. Представьте, файл назван *012017.txt*, и если просто взять `01` и отнять единицу, получится нулевой месяц, что не имеет смысла.

Поэтому используйте следующий подход (слегка модифицированный [вариант Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44947025/3832970)):

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\1\*.txt' | Rename-Item -NewName { [Regex]::Replace($_.Name, '([0-9]{6})\.txt$', {
        try {
            [DateTime]::ParseExact($args[0].Groups[1].Value, "MMyyyy", $null).AddMonths(-1).ToString("MMyyyy") + ".txt"
        } catch {
            $args[0]
        }
    })
}
```

Обойтись без функции обратного вызова нельзя.

**Обратите внимание**

- `$args[0]` — это целое совпадение (объект `Match`)
- `([0-9]{6})\.txt$`  - регулярное выражение, захватывающее в первую захватывающую группу 6 цифр, а затем точка и текст `txt` в конце строки `$`.
- `[DateTime]::ParseExact` - приводит содержимое первой захватывающей группы (`$args[0].Groups[1].Value`) к объекту *DateTime* в формате "MMyyyy", а `.AddMonths(-1)` вычитает 1, a `.ToString("MMyyyy")` снова конвертирует дату в строку.

Тест:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]